# Recover .ldf file in sql server

Tags: sql-server, ldf

i deleted manually all the .ldf file in the sql server 2008 of my local [path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA]. I am also stopped the SQL server (MSSQLServer) and then deleted. Now while i try to restart, it is throwing error.
 I come to know that i did the wrong thing. Is there any way to recover this please? or Do i need to reinstall my sql server?

Kindly reply me at the earliest.

Regards,
Viswa V.

Comment: If it is not possibile to restart SQL from management studio or console try using services.msc; once SQL is restarted verify if your database is labeled as suspect (in this case use DETACH/ATTACH) or not (in this case log file is automatically recreated).

Comment: i am not able to start from services.msc too!

Comment: Error Message: 
Windows could not start the SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) on Local Computer. For more information, review the System Event Log. If this is a non-Microsoft service, contact the service vendor, and refer to service-specific error code 3417.

Comment: Did you review the system event log?

Comment: oh yes, you delete every ldf file... google this: sql restore master database!

Comment: System Error log tells:
Unable to open the physical file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\mastlog.ldf". Operating system error 2: "2(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105)".

Comment: @tezzo: I tried googling as you recommend. unfortunately i dont have  Rebuildm.exe in my sql server

Comment: If you have not backed up your master database, then reinstall of SQL server is the simplest way. (Rebuilding master database actually overwrites it from setup media anyway.) You have to attach your work databases afterwards (may be possible even without LDF files, depend on database state).

Comment: I did this at last Arvo and now working fine. thanks guys for all your suggestions. It helped me a lot.